# Swipelistview Android

Tags: android

I am using swipe listview library in my android project and things are working fine. But the problem is I want a particular item in listview should not have swipe feature in swipelistview. Has any one used swipe listview library implemented the above ? I am saving a flag for an item which should not be swipeable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed by the latest version of [SwipeListView](http://www.slideshare.net/idsclub/melbourne-internettalk-18356180)

The cause of the this issue is that the recycled list item display the old frontView, just reset the translation X of frontView at getView() or download the latest version.